# Replace with null if a column contains only particular character

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I wan to replace a value with null if it contains #, however there can be n number of # for that column.

example:

```
Col1
'#'
'123#143#444'
'#123#'
'###'
```

For above column, I want output as

```
Col1
null
'123#143#444'
'#123#'
null
```

I am using python to handle above, but somehow not getting the desired result. Following is the part of code I am using:

`df['col1'] =df['col1'].replace('#', '')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use replace with regex:

`df.col1.replace(to_replace=r'^#+$', value=np.NaN, regex=True)`

- The `^` matches any string that starts with `#+`
- the `#` indicates the character you are trying to find (`#`)
- the `+` indicates you are looking for one or more `#`
- the `$` matches a string that ends with `#+`

##### UPDATE

If the character you are trying to replace is a special character in regex, such as `|`. You need to ignore/escape this by using `\`.

For example:
`df.col1.replace(to_replace=r'^\|+$', value=np.NaN, regex=True)`

Comment: what could be the syntax if in place of # it is pipe |, I am getting error if I replace # with I in above code

Comment: Pipe `|` is a special character in regex, so you should use: `to_replace=r'^\|+$'`. The ``\`` makes sure you ignore the regex-effect of `\` and see it as a character.

Comment: @vikasSharma if this answer helped you on your question, don't forget to accept this solution, to help future visitors of this question.